# How to view network calls by a JavaScript VM instance in a Browser

Tags: javascript, web-applications, network-programming, google-chrome-devtools

I have noticed in some websites (e.g. Stock, Video Stream) loading dynamic content. But I am unable to view those network calls from browser developer tools (I have checked all filters). Later I have noticed activity in Memory tab in Developer tools where JavaScript VM instance running making activity. Is there a way to inspect these calls?

Comment: *"I have noticed activity in Memory tab in Developer tools where JavaScript VM instance running making upload/download activity."* What are you seeing in the *Memory* tab that makes you think there's network activity?? That doesn't immediately seem to make any sense.

Comment: My bad, edited the post. It is JavaScript VM. For an example in a stock trading site, I have noticed the the prices getting updated, where I couldn't find any network calls are being made. Only activity I can see in the memory tab in developer tools where a JS VM instance is running.

Comment: It's probably an established [web socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) that you overlooked at the top of the network tab. JavaScript code running in the browser will not download things without them showing in the network tab.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I used WS filter and was able to see the activity I am looking for.